# How to get a link on a website using Python that updates dynamically?

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am trying to download the most recent zip file from the ERCOT Website (https://www.ercot.com/mp/data-products/compliance-and-disclosure/?id=NP3-965-ER). However, the link of the zip file has a doclookup id that changes everytime. The id is also populated dynamically. I have tried using beautifulsoup to get the link, but since it's being loaded dynamically it is not providing any links. Any feedback or solutions will be appreciated. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFIs7.png)

Comment: YOU will need to track the API calls that update the link

Comment: @iamtrappedman how would I do that? Can you please provide more detail? 
I am new to web scraping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the exposed api:

```
import json

import pandas as pd
import pendulum
import requests


def get_document_id(type_id: int) -> int:
    url = (
        "https://www.ercot.com/misapp/servlets/IceDocListJsonWS?"
        f"reportTypeId={type_id}&"
        f"_={pendulum.now().format('X')}"
    )

    with requests.Session() as request:
        response = request.get(url, timeout=10)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print(response.raise_for_status())

    data = json.loads(response.text)

    return pd.json_normalize(data=data["ListDocsByRptTypeRes"], record_path="DocumentList").head(1)["Document.DocID"].squeeze()


id_number = get_document_id(13052)
print(id_number)

869234127
```